# $yx^2=z$ For any interger $z$, find a whole number solution.

Tags: diophantine-equations

Given any integer $z$, what are all the integer solutions possible 
that create a square prism of length $x$ with a height of length $y$? For 
example, if $z=25$, some possibles solutions are a $5\times 5$ square prism with a 
height of $1$ or a square prism that is $1\times 1$ with a height of $25$.

Would the formula $yx^2=z$ be a way to figure this out and would this be a diophantine equation?

Comment: I forgot a cube is the same length in all three axes, I should change it to a rectangular prism with two faces having a length of $x$. Edit: Square Prism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $yx^2=z$ is a good way to represent the situation and if you demand that all the variables be naturals it is a Diophantine equation.  Now if you factor $z$ you can find the solutions easily.  $x$ can be any factor that you can square, then $y$ is what is left.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Think about taking a prime factorization of $z$.  If $z=x^2y$, then every prime power divisor of $z$ must be accounted for by either $x^2$ or $y$.  What sort of powers can $x^2$ actually take care of, and what sort must be taken care of by $y$?